# How to render data from parse in next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I want to render data in client side below from parse after signin from next auth using `useSession`

```json
{
  objectId: 'nttMcKIOQJ',
  username: 'fiik346',
  email: 'fiik346@gmail.com',
  createdAt: '2022-06-26T07:56:41.888Z',
  updatedAt: '2022-06-26T07:56:41.888Z',
  ACL: { '*': { read: true }, nttMcKIOQJ: { read: true, write: true } },
  sessionToken: 'r:2f2c569be3b5120f3893834c2ace7b67'
}
```

But it's  just render email

```json
{"user": {"email":"fiik346@gmail.com"},"expires":"2022-07-26T09:01:41.163Z"}
"authenticated"
```

This is my callbacks code

```js
// /pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
...

callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {           // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.                             return session
    },                                                async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {                                             return token
    }                                               },

...
```

And client side code

```js
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
export default function accountIndex() {
  const {data: session, status} = useSession()      return (                                            <div>
      <h1>Account is {status}</h1>
      <pre className="overflow-auto">
        {JSON.stringify(session)}
        <br/>
        {JSON.stringify(status)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know how to change my callbacks code to display data from database

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I try my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while and try harder, I was successful to render data. Just change callback code like below.

```js
...

callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {           
        // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.                             
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken           
        session.user = token.data                          
        return session                                  
    },                                               
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {                                             
        if (user) {                                         
            token.data = user                               
        }      
        return token    
    }  
},

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({token, user}) => {
      if (user) {
        token.data = user
      }
      return token
    },
    session: async ({session, token}) => {
      if (token.data) {
        session.user = token.data
      }
      return session
    }
  }
```